# Cant login to wp-admin or as author again

Tags: login, xampp

my wordpress login page is not directing me to admin dashboard after accepting password, it remain on same page without any issues. l have try serval solutions on the net but the problem remains the same and  facing this issues for 3 days now.  how do l fix this problem plssss?

[[image: here is a screenshot of the login page1]

Comment: Did you [enable mod_headers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48541069/299509)?

Comment: That doesn't look like a WordPress login to me, neither the page nor the URL.

Comment: that is wordpress bro